# How to stop scrolling inside panel and only allow listview to scroll

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, scroll, appframework

i have a panel that contains a div that needs to not scroll when someone is scrolling down the listview, as is stands right now when i scroll it scrolls the whole entire panel. Im using Intel XDK NEW with App Framework 2.0, jQuery and JQM. Here is what i have please see comments

```
<div id="home" class="panel" data-nav="home-nav" data-load="loadDashData">
                <header>
                    <h1>test</h1>
                </header>
                <div id="dashUserInfo" class="user-info"> //THIS IS THE DIV I DONT WANT SCROLLING
                    <div class="white-strip">
                        <h1 id="dashUserFullName" class="user-fullname">Aaron Russell</h1>
                        <h2 id="dashNotifications" class="user-new-notification-count">no new notifications</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="dashAvatarHolder" class="avatar">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="listHolder"> // THIS IS THE ONLY THING THAT SHOULD SCROLL
                    <ul id="dashList" class="list">
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <footer>
                    <a href="#home" style="float:left;" id="tabButton" class="atme-icon-home active-icon" data-transition="none"></a>

                    <a href="#inbox" id="tabButton" class="atme-icon-chat-empty" data-transition="none"></a>

                    <a href="#contact" style="float:right;" id="tabButton" class="atme-icon-user" data-transition="none"></a>
                </footer>
            </div>
```

I have tried every possibility for setting the `.user-info` to fixed adding a margin-top to the listview. THat did not work. I tried the style="overflow: hidden" technique commonly used on panels to stop scrolling on the panel then adding style="overflow:visible" to the listview i want to scroll, that failed as well. I dont know what to do now.

Maybe a jQuery script i can call to the div that i dont want to scroll?

EDIT: i thought of a way i could do it, i could disable all scrolling through the app and only enable it on listview divs with a specific class... however im not familiar how to acheive the last part happen. I know how to disable all native scrolling...

Comment: `.listHolder { overflow-y: scroll; }`?

Comment: Use that with disabling native scrolling?

Comment: No, just add this with a fixed height, the div will scroll.

Comment: That still scrolls everything inside the panel. setting things to a fixed position just makes it act like its absolute. Want me to setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure, it will help. Fixed height not position, `height: 10em` for example.

Comment: Okay so i got the listview scrolling seperately however the panel still scrolls with it.

Comment: Ahh got it! Had to set the panel to overflow:hidden... thank you so much.. If you put it in an answer i'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I'm glad I've been of help :)